# how to use distinct in aggregate for $sample in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, unique, distinct, sample

i have some questions in my db with same "time"
so i want get some unique Based on "time" question

my db :

```
    {
    "_id": "5e7f85d7e06d0000290013b7",
    "id_user": "5e7f845ae06d00032746013b2",
    "id_paretnt": "5e7533afa1345350a5005bf5",
    "question": "how is this",
    "fakeAnswer": [
        {
            "answer": "anika"
        },
        {
            "answer": "monique"
        },
        {
            "answer": "jack"
        }
    ],
    "id_userAdded": "5e7f845ae06d0000290013b2",
    "answer": "berad",
    "time": 1585594066.0
}
```

my simple code

```
    db.questions.aggregate(
   [ { $sample: { size: 3 } } ]
)
```

o/p doesn't matter just any o/p

Comment: the "time" filed type is a "int"   like  "time":130

Comment: Can you provide sample docs & required o/p !!

Comment: edit question with sample data , thanks

Comment: So for each distinct `time` in collection you want 3 distinct docs ?

Comment: yes but best References

Comment: What does this *best References* mean ?

Comment: I mean the server resources so it doesn't go down

Comment: *I mean the server resources so it doesn't go down* - completely not understandable !!

Comment: Don't worry, you have an idea for the question

Comment: So here is the thing you could easily do this :: get 3 distinct docs for each distinct `time` !! But you might always get those same old 3 docs for a given time for subsequent requests, (Basically if you want distinct docs on sub-sequent requests then it's not easy in your case - let me know if that's the case & I understand it correct)..